# Cannot connect to the internet on my iPhone 4S after upgrading to iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, internet

Just updated the iOS to 5.1 this morning and now I cannot connect to the internet. WiFi is not available to me right now...

Comment: What happens if you go to Settings → Wi-Fi? Does the network you want to connect to not show up, or do you get an error when you’re trying to connect? Which error?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have Wi Fi access here at my job. But yesterday I did not have this problem in the office...I was able to connect to my email & Pandora with my 3g service. Now all I get is a msg saying "cannot connect to the server"

Comment: Ah, so it’s not necessarily a WiFi issue. I’ve undeleted [my answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45191/4408) — that’s probably your problem. (I had it too after the upgrade.)

Comment: @MathiasBynens this is not a wifi specific issue, rather a internet connectivity problem or maybe a 3g connectivity issue? I can receive & send texts + make phone calls - but not use any applications that rely on the internet connection, ie. email, calendar, or pandora.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to re-enter the network settings. Updating iOS seems to wipe these settings.

Go to Settings → General → Network → Cellular Data Network and enter all fields.

---

[To use a VPN connection](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1424), Choose Settings → General → Network → VPN and then choose “Add VPN Configuration”. Ask your company’s IT guy for the credentials.

Comment: I'm assuming it's the VPN info I have to enter? Where do I get the correct information to input?

Comment: @wbg My answer explained how to set up and/or reset a 3G or Edge connection. I’ve added some info related to setting up a VPN.

Comment: @wbg If my answer was helpful to you, please upvote it and mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark (`√`) next to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting you network settings. Go to Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings. This should do the trick - it did for me.

You will have to enter WiFi keys again, but that's the only downside.

Comment: Rest the network setting...no such luck.